# Sorry the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration. Please download the latest version of the application. - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I have followed the Facebook integration tutorial here http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/
And the Facebook window opens but hen it displays the error message - sorry the application you are using is mis... The odd thing is if I click for espanol in the Facebook window and then back to english it works just fine. I am very confused with this and don't understand the tutorial on Facebook.developers.com. Please help. Also would love to now if there were an easier way to implement Facebook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I got the same error, and dont really know what the solution is,but..
I used the ApiKey and the SecretKey of this application: (I downloaded the MyGradesTutorial sample project, and took the key's to my application and)  it worked smooth! 
what does it mean is that the problem is probably in Facebook application and not in mine (yours) code!
I still searching for the solution from Facebook app side...